# How to query latest version of Delta Lake table in Azure Synapse?

Tags: azure-synapse, delta-lake

How can we use **Azure Synapse serverless SQL pool** to query the **latest version of Delta Lake table** ??

Below link specifies it can be done under Delta Lake, but unable to find any examples:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/resources-self-help-sql-on-demand#delta-lake

*"You can use serverless SQL pool to query the latest version of Delta Lake"*

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for querying Delta tables in Synapse Serverless SQL is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/query-delta-lake-format?). Basically the syntax looks like:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM OPENROWSET(
    BULK 'https://sqlondemandstorage.blob.core.windows.net/delta-lake/covid/',
    FORMAT = 'delta') as rows;
```

Comment: I am specifically looking for getting the latest version of the delta table which have the last changed snapshot of the table. If the table is updated daily with inserts & updates...I want to view the last/latest snapshot of the delta. above query in serverless pool would give me the entire snapshot of all the changes since here we are pointing to the root delta folder. I am specifically looking for as of timestamp and/or as of version kind of statements like you could run on spark/databricks cluster. I could read the latest version from Azure Mapping Data Flow but need an example using SQL.

Comment: in Synapse Serverless SQL pool.

Comment: @ManiK the example query I provided will show the most up-to-date information from the delta table. If in Spark with 5 separate statements row A was inserted, row B inserted, row B updated, row A deleted, and then row C inserted, a query against that delta table would return 2 rows (B and C). So it’s the latest version meaning the most up-to-date information. It doesn’t support time travel queries currently (see the link you provided) or the ability to only pull the most recently changed rows (unless that’s indicated by a column you can filter on manually).

Comment: @ManiK if you used `FORMAT = 'PARQUET’` against a Delta table folder then you would get a mess back with multiple copies of rows that have updates and you would see deleted rows.

Comment: agree, we have to use FORMAT='DELTA' not 'PARQUET' as per documentation. However, lately - it turned out to be an issue within our dataflow logic wherein few records inserts/update were messed up and we were to blame DELTA showing incorrect latest version/snapshot. My bad :(. I think if the documentation would have been updated to make it very clear with a one-liner statement that this query always returns the latest version/snapshot  of the Delta table, would have been helpful. Although, it does mention that time travel currently isn't supported. Anyways, thanks a lot.

Comment: @GregGalloway, going by your example row A was inserted, row B inserted, row B updated, row A deleted and if NO changes done on row D, row E, row F etc.., then serverless SQL query should not return the the unchaged rows but only recently changes rows i.e., only B and C as per your example. Do we have such kind of possibilities? Requirement is to trigger the downstrean pipeline with incremental changes NOT to send entire dataset if only one/few rows get updated/inserted.

Comment: @191180rk I don’t believe that Synapse Serverless SQL supports that functionality currently unless you add a timestamp column or similar to track what has changed yourself. You could use a Spark notebook to use the time travel feature of Delta to get this.

Answer (score 0):

For delta lake/parquet, it seems to me you have to do survivorship using the versionnumber.  You can do that inside of a view to provide the current version of data in the external table.  Note that the view must be in a separate schema or you could create the view in a separate Sql database within that workspace (not the lake database).

For example,

### with cte as
(
select id, versionnumber, row_number() over (partition by id order by versionnumber desc) as row_nbr
from  [dbo].[account]
)

SELECT a.*
FROM [dbo].[account] a
inner join cte on cte.Id = a.id where cte.row_nbr = 1